# In what ways can I separately manage entries in Contacts.app and SIM card contacts?

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, sim, import

I have some basic questions in my mind and ofcourse, I should ask them to know the things.

- Can I import/export contacts from/to sim card?
- Is it possible to view the contacts that are stored in sim/iPhone separately?
- Is it possible to choose the default memory storage for contacts?
- Is it possible to delete all contacts from sim/iPhone (or maybe both)by one click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answers are only about usual not jailbreaked iPhone

- You can import contact from SIM, [more on this here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4994?viewlocale=en_US). It's not possible to export contacts to the card.
- It is not possible to view the contacts that are stored on sim/iPhone separately.
- The default memory storage for contacts is iPhone memory. Can't be changed.
- [Here is a universal way](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WzKDA9rAFo0) to delete all contacts from Address Book. iPhone can't delete contacts from SIM card.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete all/multiple iPhone contacts at once if you have jailbroken your iPhone or if not, as shown in this [YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_H_swgEAAM) instead.

You can export iPhone contacts to your SIM only if you have jailbroken your iPhone or via some third party app.